# Syntax error detected between FORMAT and <

Tags: fortran

Error message:

```
Z:\INCLUDE\APRSER.INC(102): error FOR3852: syntax error detected between FORMAT and <
Z:\INCLUDE\APRSER.INC(122): error FOR3852: syntax error detected between FORMAT and <

FORMAT HAS BEEN DECLARED AS: 
    CHARACTER*5    FORMAT
```

Code:

```
             ELSE

                WRITE (FORMAT(3:4),'(I2)',
     *                         IOSTAT=STATUS(I)) COMMAS(I) - CST
                         READ (STRING(CST:COMMAS(I) - 1),FORMAT,
     *                                IOSTAT=STATUS(I)) ITEMP(I)      
             ENDIF             
             CST = COMMAS(I) + 1 
  100    CONTINUE         
         TOTSER = TOTCOM + 1
         IF (RLEN .LT. CST) THEN
            ITEMP(TOTSER) = 0               
         ELSE
            WRITE (FORMAT(3:4),'(I2)',
     *                         IOSTAT=STATUS(TOTSER)) RLEN - CST + 1          
            READ (STRING(CST:RLEN),FORMAT,
     *                         IOSTAT=STATUS(TOTSER)) ITEMP(TOTSER)     
         ENDIF
```

> ```
> Z:\INCLUDE\APRSER.INC(102): error FOR3852: syntax error detected
> between FORMAT and <  
> Z:\INCLUDE\APRSER.INC(122): error FOR3852: syntax
> error detected between FORMAT and <
> ```

Comment: Welcome, please take the [tour], read [ask] and learn how to format your questions here.

Comment: At a minimum line numbers would help

Comment: Better post a full [mcve] which we can try to compile ourselves. You should also tell us which compiler do you use.